# Geometry Node - Strawberry seeds distribution (checker pattern)

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes

I got help here just a few minutes ago to set up a geometry node that looks like this.

[image]

Now I want to skip some of the instances. So it looks more like a strawberry. Like every other or every third. And I also want every row to be offset. Is this possible with geometry nodes?

Comment: Since strawberry seeds are very regular but not *perfectly* regular, I found that using Distribute Points -> Poisson Disk with a defined minimum distance to be a good solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably would be easier to enhance your base model first ... A topology closer to a strawberry seed like pattern ... rhombs.

- Add Plane orientated on X axis (with Apply > Rotation Ctrl+A), aspect ratio 2:1, split in middle Ctrl+R

Modifiers:

- Subdivision > Simple > 4
- Simple Deform > Bend > 180 X
- Simple Deform > Bend > 360 Z

... or just add UV Sphere :)

- Simple Deform > Taper > Target Object > Empty
- **Decimate > Un-Subdiv > 1** (to get rhomb pattern)

[image]

- Geometry Nodes for seeds instancing

[image]

Comment: Yeah this helped. I needed to change the mesh to make sure they were in the right place. In the end I ended up making a vertex selection and adding it to a particle system, but after playing around with geometry nodes I think this is a simpler and way less "work-around-y" solution.

Comment: I didn't hade to remake my mesh, I just decimated it once to get angled faces. It worked!

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

> Note: Be aware that the result depends on your geometry sizes, so it will not work for "every" geometry.

[image]

> Note: you need Blender 3.1 in order to open and check out the example blend file

*** UPDATE ***

one way, which of course is a bit tedious, to make it look a bit more like a stawberry pattern, is to go to edit mode with the uvsphere, select an edge loop like this:

[image]

and then rotate on z-axis with transform orientation set to normal:

[image]

so that you get this:

[image]

i just did this now for one edge loop, but if you do this for every second edge loop, it will look good.

So mine (because i am lazy) looks now like this:

[image]

```
Note: I just rotated one edge loop here. You should move every second.
```

*** UPDATE 2 ***

i just found out an easier solution for this:

[image]

```
Note: you can cut off the top and bottom part as i described above.
```

Comment: please ... Can you enhanced your A with a way for checker selection, so the final result will be closer to strawberry seed pattern? Otherwise it will generates third Q on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: i updated my answer. Unfortunately the checker select tool didn't help in that case.

Comment: @vklidu: i found a more elegant solution and updated my answer again.

Comment: Great the selection with Modulo :) Any hint how to make it work for GN Mesh Primitive UV Sphere? BTW If you mean checker deselect operator it works great - select all, deselect top and bottom vertex and than use Checker Deselect, Assign selection to a Vertex Group and use it as Attribute directly to Selection socket.

Answer (score 4):

For strawberry seed distribution you can start with default Icosphere, Subdivided, Smooth modifier ...

[image]

Than based on this topology use any kind of instancing technique per Vertex ...

[image]